# Unknown Google Account Signed into Browser

Tags: wifi, account-security, google, firefox, lan

An unknown Google account is signed into Firefox on my Arch Linux machine. The computer is in my apartment (where I live alone) and I lock the screen when I leave.

Some observations:

- The unknown account is has a domain of `@pages.plusgoogle.com` and a random-number-looking user name.
- The "Signing in to Google" page for the unknown account shows no password option: [image: shows no password option].
- The Google Timeline for the unknown account is the same as my real account.
- The unknown account is now NOT showing up in new tabs when selecting a Google account, however, I still have tabs open that are logged into the unknown account.
- The only machine listed under my devices in the unknown account's "Your devices" section is the current Arch Linux machine.
- My real account has 2FA using the Google Authenticator app (and the backup codes are unused and unchanged)
- My real account shows no unknown devices logged in

Searching for things like "unknown Google account logged into laptop browser" only results in suggestions that someone has gained physical access to your laptop. This is of course not impossible, but it is unlikely. Has someone broken in to my apartment or my wifi/lan?

My question is to ask people's advice or thoughts here. I am a software engineer but I only have rudimentary security knowledge at best.

Comment: Have you tried: https://myaccount.google.com/support ? I think they're all 24/7. TBH I don't have any clue either.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Google (owner of Youtube) creates brand accounts tied to pages.plusgoogle.com domain if you change a name on your YouTube channel. If you own a Youtube channel, that's where it probably came from. More information here: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9367690?hl=en